# Achieving high-performance transactions when extending PostgreSQL with C-functions

Tags: c, postgresql

My goal is to achieve the highest performance available for copying a block of data from the database into a C-function to be processed and returned as the result of a query.

I am new to PostgreSQL and I am currently researching possible ways to move the data. Specifically, I am looking for nuances or keywords related specifically to PostgreSQL to move big data fast.

**NOTE:**
*My ultimate goal is speed, so I am willing to accept answers outside of the exact question I have posed as long as it gets big performance results. For example, I have come across the COPY keyword (PostgreSQL only), which moves data from tables to files quickly; and vice versa. I am trying to stay away from processing that is external to the database, but if it provides a performance improvement that out-weighs the obvious drawback of external processing, then so be it.*

Comment: Are you talking about running a c function on a particular record, or running the function on all records in the table?  Also, how big is the data that you're wanting to process and how big is the result?

Comment: The table has millions of records and in a perfect world I would transform an entire column of a table in one shot. Currently, the function is running on one record per call, but I want to fetch multiple (let's say 1000 at first then scaling up as the opportunity presents itself or as it makes sense) rows at once and perform the operation on multiple rows at once.

Comment: Note that `COPY` can only load data into a *table*, not a function. For most people it makes sense to `COPY` data into a table, then process it with functions.

Comment: I think you are talking about NoSQL databases here. Because `SQL` and `Performance` are two words that don't cope together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you probably want to use the [server programming interface (SPI)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/spi.html) to implement a stored procedure as a [C language function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-c.html) running inside the PostgreSQL back-end.

Use [`SPI_connect`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/spi-spi-connect.html) to set up the SPI.

Now [`SPI_prepare_cursor`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/spi-spi-prepare-cursor.html) a query, then [`SPI_cursor_open`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/spi-spi-cursor-open.html) it. [`SPI_cursor_fetch`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/spi-spi-cursor-fetch.html) rows from it and [`SPI_cursor_close`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/spi-spi-cursor-close.html) it when done. Note that `SPI_cursor_fetch` allows you to fetch batches of rows.

[`SPI_finish`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/spi-spi-finish.html) to clean up when done.

You can return the result rows into a tuplestore as you generate them, avoiding the need to build the whole table in memory. See examples in any of the set-returning functions in the PostgreSQL source code. You might also want to look at the [`SPI_returntuple`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/spi-spi-returntuple.html) helper function.

See also: [C language functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-c.html) and [extending SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/extend.html).

If maximum speed is of interest, your client may want to use the libpq binary protocol via [libpqtypes](http://libpqtypes.esilo.com/) so it receives the data produced by your server-side SPI-using procedure with minimal overhead.

Comment: To clairfy, I am using C-language functions (inside the database) and I am looking for the fastest way to move multiple rows through my C-language function, instead of it being a row by row call.

Comment: @Zak Yep, and this is probably the fastest way. The SPI is used for C-language functions inside the DB. It's kind of like libpq for C user-defined procedures running in the DB. An SPI query with batch cursor fetching is likely to be your best bet, unless you want to try to hook into the query executor directly (warning: scary, there be dragons, don't do that). Clarified final par to make it clear that's just an aside and that the rest applies to server-side/spi.

Comment: @Zak a quick "git grep" suggests you'll find samples for SPI  in `contrib/spi/`, and real-world examples in `contrib/dblink` and `contrib/tablefunc` among other places.

Comment: I have one more question about the SPI, is it safe to use SPI in multi thread mode? Say, multiple thread run read only SELECT query using SPI. I find that the SPI_exec / SPI_execute are not thread safe because they depend on some global variables. How about the cursor-like functions ?

Comment: @qiuxiafei Please post a new question for that, and paste a link to it in these comments.