# Postgresql SPI: Manipulating type "Datum" to create a double array

Tags: c, postgresql

I am using `SPI_getbinval` to pull a column of type `double precision[]` from my cursor. How can I reconstruct this as a `double *` in C so I can work with the values?

Most of the examples I've seen in the documentation make reference to obscure helper functions (i.e. `construct_md_array()`) and I cannot find a listing of these functions or how to use them appropriately for my situation.

Basically, I need to know the most efficient way to construct a `double` array from `Datum` containing `double precision[]`.

(See prior question [Achieving high-performance transactions when extending PostgreSQL with C-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13236714/398670)).

Comment: This might be interesting: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3e3c86f90802281153o15e70724u425cdd0173bb2373@mail.gmail.com . Also check out the `intarray` contrib module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...    
bool is_null = true;
Datum raw_array = SPI_getbinval(heap_tuple, tuple_desc, column_of_array, &is_null);

if ( !is_null ) {
    ArrayType *pg_array = DatumGetArrayTypeP(raw_array);
    int array_dimensionality = ARR_NDIM(pg_array);

    // Not prepared for multi-dimension array
    if ( array_dimensionality == 1 ) {
        double *c_array = VARDATA(pg_array);  // Pointer to the array data
        int array_size = ARR_DIMS(pg_array)[0];  // Element count of array at [dimension]

        // Cycle through a single dimension array
        for (int i = 0 ; i < array_size ; ++i) {
            elog(INFO, "Double value at element %d: %lf\n", i, c_array[i]);
        }
    }
}
...
```

P.S. `elog()` is PostgreSQL version of the `printf()` function (with additional functionality) - use it.